# Database doesn't exist/not being loaded in built app with Expo

Tags: android, database, sqlite, react-native, expo

I'm trying to launch a React-Native and Expo app, but I'm having one big issue: The app uses a premade SQLite database to read and update information.

This database gets loaded into the app the first time it launches, or if the version has been updated (via a simple variable).

I tested the app with no issues via the Expo Client, but now that I'm trying it in a phone (via an APK), there's no database, and I have no clue why it's not working.

The code that loads the database:

```js
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
  Asset.fromModule(require('../databases/programs.db')).uri,
  `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/programs-${version}.db`
).then(() => {
  programsDB = SQLite.openDatabase(`programs-${version}.db`);
  loadDB(loaded);
});
```

I have this in `metro.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/amplify\/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
    assetExts: ["db", "ttf", "png", "jpg"]
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

And this in `app.json`:

```json
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "src/library/assets/**/*",
  "src/library/databases/*",
  "src/library/fonts/*"
],
"packagerOpts": {
  "assetExts": ["db"]
},
```

I've tried both with:

```js
require('../databases/programs.db'
```

and:

```js
require('library/databases/programs.db'
```

After the app tries to load stuff from the database, I get the following error:

> Directory for /data/user/0/com.company.myApp/files/SQLite/programs-2020052401.db doesn't exist

I also tried changing the source database to download from `.db` to `.mp4`, but it doesn't do it either.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

After tinkering with it to isolate the problem I ended up finding out that the issue was that the directory (SQLite) where the database is going to be saved in the devices wasn't being created with downloadAsync, which I would have known if I had read the docs more carefully.
I just had to make the directory first if it didn't exist and then it worked alright.

Here's how the coded ended up looking:

```js
// Check if the directory where we are going to put the database exists
let dirInfo;
try {
    dirInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite`);
} catch(err) { Sentry.captureException(err) };
  
if (!dirInfo.exists) {
  try {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite`, { intermediates: true });
  } catch(err) { Sentry.captureException(err) }
};

// Downloads the db from the original file
// The db gets loaded as read only
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
  Asset.fromModule(require('../databases/programs.db')).uri,
    `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/programs${version}.db`
  ).then(() => {
  programsDB = SQLite.openDatabase(`programs${version}.db`); // We open our downloaded db
  loadDB(loaded); // We load the db into the persist store
}).catch(err => Sentry.captureException(err));
```