# How to create persistant SQLite database for React Native and expo that sync with local drive for development?

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, expo

I want to add an SQLite database to my expo project. And I have those requirements:

- When run for the first time the `file.db` is created in the emulator and on a local drive
- I want the file to be persistent in the emulator and on the local drive
- the copy from local drive to mobile app can happen when I start the app (this is only for dev env).

I'm not sure how do this. I was asking chatGPT but it enter a loop and was giving me the code that had the same error. The chatGPT was adding this code:

```js
const asset = Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/mydatabase.db'));
```

But this will throw an error when assets don't have this file.

So what I want with this is that I want to have proper dev env when the database will not be in the git repository but it will be created when the code runs for the first time. And I want to inspect the local database to check what is inside add new stuff manually and see the changes in the Android emulator when I restart the app. And when I add something to the database I want everything to be in the database even If I delete the emulator. I can also share the SQLite database file with other people.

I hope the question is not too broad but it seems that what I need is:

- check if the file exists in the assets directory
- check if the file exists in the mobile app directory
- copy the file form assets to the mobile app and the other way around
- run the first copy on start the app
- run the second copy after every query or when I do some kind of action

How can I create dev env with SQLite database that is saved in the assets directory so you can inspect and modify and the modifications in the app are reflected in the local file?

Comment: For a development environment, see: [How to use ADB in Android Studio to view an SQLite DB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18370219/295004) Generally if your Android app needs to have pre-existing data at build time there are ways to get it in the APK. For Expo you may want to look at: [Database doesn't exist/not being loaded in built app with Expo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61995979/295004)